# Map timezone in query from postgresql to jpql

Tags: java, postgresql, jpql

I would like to map my postgresql query to jpql query in java. And I can't map "created AT time zone 'UTC' AT time zone 'Europe/Paris'" .

My postgresql query:

```
SELECT count(*), to_char(created AT time zone 'UTC' AT time zone 'Europe/Paris','DD-MM-YYYY') 
from my_table GROUP BY to_char(created AT time zone 'UTC' AT time zone 'Europe/Paris','DD-MM-YYYY');
```

My jpql query:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("select count(z), to_char(z.created, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), z.formType from MyTableEntity z where z.created >= :startFrom and z.created <= :endTo GROUP BY to_char(z.created, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), z.formType ");
```

How can I group by my created field in timestamp 'Europe/Paris'? In database created field is saved in timestamp. AT time zone  in jpql doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `to_char` to convert dates to a string at all. Let JPA handle the conversion. Also PostgreSQL can store a timestamp, but it does not store a time zone. It only stores the offset of the timezone at the given moment.

What you can do to get these results by date is casting to date, rather than using formatting. Here's how it would look as a native query:

```
SELECT count(*), cast(created AS date), form_type from my_table
GROUP BY cast(created AS date), form_type;
```

And in JPQL:

```
SELECT count(z), cast(z.created as date), z.formType from MyTableEntity z
where z.created between :startFrom and :endTo
GROUP BY cast(z.created as date), z.formType
```

The `a between x and y` statement is equivalent to `a >= x and a <= y`.

And if your database runs on a server who's default timezone is `Europe/Paris`, you don't need that timezone conversion. Alternatively you can run a native query to set the timezone for your current connection https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-set.html and then run your other queries.

```
SET SESSION TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris'
```

Comment: ok, thanks. I understand, that there is no any equivalent function to "at time zone"?

Comment: It is one of many features JPQL is lacking. And when it comes to time zones, so do MySQL and MariaDB, who are among the most popular databases.

Comment: ok, thanks. So, I have to use my sql. Unless I can do it in for example criteria API? I try to avoid sql. Project should be scalable to other databses.

Comment: In that case, it's best you ensure your setup always uses UTC everywhere, and doesn't rely on timezone information, if possible. I realize that's not always possible, because I have a project that cannot avoid cross-timezone data when you have to keep a schedule with departure in one TZ, and arrival in another.

Comment: Yes, I always try to keep date in UTC, but in this case I would like to do some statisctics (How many entities were created in my time zone on indviduals days). That's why I want to change time zone :)